C Programming language ansi c edition line counter
I have the following code from Kernighan & Ritchie's book:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, nl;
    nl = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
return 0;
}


I understand how it works and what should it do in theory. What I don't understand is, what's happening in reality.
When I run the program (on windows) and write some text that consists of two lines for example, then I press ctrl z, the program completely closes itself. I don't understand where or how should it show me the lines my text contained.
I would gladly appreciate some help or explanation.
I expected the program to show me the number of lines in a text. In reality, it just closes itself.

Run it from a Command Prompt window, not the IDE. The IDE is closing the output window when the program finishes, so you never see the result.

Thank you for the suggestion! I do run it in command prompt. Well, to be more exact, I run the .exe file which opens a command prompt in which the program runs. But still, the prompt just disappears when I press ctrl z.

@BenceSárközi You should launch the program from an already existing command prompt.

Thank you! It's working this way. Much appreciated.

Ctrl+z in the Windows (and Linux & others) command line suspends the process. What you really want to do is signal the end of file using Ctl+d.
Note, if you press Ctl+d when the above program is NOT running you may signal to the command line an end of file and it may close (this happens to me on Linux when I'm not paying attention).

Well, no. Ctrl-Z means "EOF" in Windows' CMD, it is mainly a legacy of DOS, and before that,of CP/M.
